# Octal permissions of the directories /usr/lib?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

Anyone know?

1.What are the octal permissions of the directories /usr/lib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stat -c "%a %n" /usr/lib
755 /usr/lib
```

So octal permissions of the directories **/usr/lib** is 755